# Mollie webhook URL called but payment id not getting

Tags: mollie

We have already created issues and this similar this https://github.com/mollie/api-documentation/issues/583

We have set webhook URL the id parameter in request but every time we got id is null so my question is id parameter are we pass or your side passed the parameter? let me know we are big trouble at this moment.

Create a payment response

```
{
    "resource": "payment",
    "id": "tr_pCHpdCbpb5",
    "mode": "test",
    "createdAt": "2020-01-24T09:40:18+00:00",
    "amount": {
        "value": "100.10",
        "currency": "EUR"
    },
    "description": "46-201800046",
    "method": null,
    "metadata": null,
    "status": "open",
    "isCancelable": false,
    "expiresAt": "2020-01-24T09:55:18+00:00",
    "profileId": "pfl_wv9K6uRbg7",
    "sequenceType": "oneoff",
    "redirectUrl": "http://localhost:60991/nl-nl/OrderValidation?paymentType=mollie",
    "webhookUrl": "https://devee05.solvisoft.net/api/mollie/webhook",
    "_links": {
        "self": {
            "href": "https://api.mollie.com/v2/payments/tr_pCHpdCbpb5",
            "type": "application/hal+json"
        },
        "checkout": {
            "href": "https://www.mollie.com/payscreen/select-method/pCHpdCbpb5",
            "type": "text/html"
        },
        "documentation": {
            "href": "https://docs.mollie.com/reference/v2/payments-api/create-payment",
            "type": "text/html"
        }
    }
}
```

When we paid amount specific to payment method Webhook URL automatically called but we got id every time null, but we detected or auto mapped currently created payment id? in webhook URL.

Comment: Show us how you are handling the actual incoming webhook request then …?

Comment: For just testing purpose I have created the `method` ` public virtual HttpResponseMessage Webhook(string id)
        {
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            string filePath = "Path"
            try
            {
                string mollieResponse = new MollieService(_apiKey).Get(string.Concat("payments/", id));
                sb.AppendLine("ID - " + id);             
                sb.Clear();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
              //erro log set
            }           
        }`

Comment: Is there any way to get recent created payment id in mollie becue we are got hold response when we created payment but main question is when we are are send the request in mollie server we pass the `Webhook` URL and `redirect UR` after payment user back in the `redirect URL` but webhook URL call in background but `id` is empty way?  mollie webhook URL - `https://docs.mollie.com/guides/webhooks`

Comment: What is `"webhookUrl": "https://devee05.solvisoft.net/api/mollie/webhook?id=TestID"` supposed to be? Why does that contain a GET parameter named `id` at this point?

Comment: If I'm not sending in parameter mollie not sending any id? just for testing purpose I passed the `TestID`

Comment: Is there any way to get `payment` after payment status change in the mollie server auto called any callback URL?

Comment: _“If I'm not sending in parameter mollie not sending any id?”_ - what gave you that idea? That should most likely be just `https://devee05.solvisoft.net/api/mollie/webhook` at this point.

Comment: If we don't pass `payment id` in webhook URL `(while Create payment API call)` then when provider automatically calls webhook URL. is that contains `paymentId` in post-call of `webhook`?

Comment: You just specify the endpoint URL under which you want to receive this, no extra parameters. They will then make a POST request to that URL, and include a parameter named `id` with that. I don’t know how that could be put any simpler or clearer.

Comment: i am facing similar issue and from mollie support i didn't receive any response

Comment: hi @NishangRaiyani, please check this https://stackoverflow.com/a/59897425/5855884

Comment: @jishansiddique i want to integrate in nodejs   so this is not possible in nodejs
if you have another solution so please provide i highly appreciate it

Comment: Sorry @NishangRaiyani, I was not aware of this. just a request if you found the solution could you please add the answer? so if anyone finds the issue he/she can get the right path.

Comment: @jishansiddique  Certainly! If I find a solution, I will share it here.

Answer (score 1):

If you are struggling with the webhook controller method appearing not to be properly called: prefix the `id` parameter with the `[FromForm]` attribute. With that, the `id` value is nicely available.

As the [documentation](https://docs.mollie.com/guides/webhooks) points out, the request made by Mollie is form encoded:

```
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
```

My controller method looks like this:

```
[HttpPost, Route("paymentstatus", Name = nameof(NotifyPaymentStatusChange))]
public async Task<IActionResult> NotifyPaymentStatusChange([FromForm] string id)
{
    // Use the received id value to continue the payment verification process ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Hello all I'm getting the webhook URL data using `Request content`

```
 public virtual HttpResponseMessage Webhook(string id)
{
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    string filePath = System.Web.Hosting.HostingEnvironment.MapPath("~/MollieLog/MollieStatus.txt");
    HttpContent requestContent = Request.Content;
    string jsonContent = requestContent.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
    sb.AppendLine("Request content - " + jsonContent);

    try
    {
        string mollieResponse = new MollieService(_apiKey).Get(string.Concat("payments/", id));
        sb.AppendLine("ID - " + id);
        sb.AppendLine("Current Date Time " + DateTime.Now);
        sb.AppendLine(mollieResponse);
        sb.AppendLine(Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(Request.Headers));               
        sb.AppendLine("---------------------------------------");
        File.AppendAllText(filePath, sb.ToString());
        sb.Clear();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        sb.AppendLine("Error " + ex.Message);       
        File.AppendAllText(filePath, sb.ToString());
    }
    return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK);
}
```

> Output

```
Request content - id=tr_dCCujJWqK9
```